# “Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=8000]” on Texpad

Tags: texpad, capacity

I use the Texpad on my iPad.
A "TeX capacity exceeded, [save size=8000]" issue occurred when compiling the project.

How to fix?

Comment: Please add the document for what the error happens to your question.

Comment: @siracusa I think this error irrespective to any document. It just depend on the size of document.

Comment: Then paste any document that doesn't work for you, so that we can check if we get the same error.

Comment: Does your document compile correctly when using a "normal" TeX installation?

Comment: @Mico When I use a Windows 10, my document is compiled correctly. This document has this issue on iPad.

Comment: In the working version look at the last line of the log it will be something like `25i,0n,19p,109b,1000s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,1000s` Take note of the `s` number (it will be bigger than 8000 but then you will have to contact the maintainers of the ipad implementation and ask if the stack can be made larger. But most likely you can change your macros not to fill the stack so much.

Comment: in a sample of over 3000 tex log files I only have 6 that use more than 8000 save stack and at least two of those were specifically testing stack use.

Answer (score 2):

Almost always if you use up the save stack you have some construct making local and global assignments to the same thing, which uses up an arbitrary amount of stack, so increasing TeX's stack size (if that is possible on the ipad implementation) probably won't help and you will need to correct the macros.

for example this document will run out of save stack in any implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


{
\loop
\dimen0=3pt
\global\dimen0=4pt
\iftrue
\repeat
}
\end{document}
```

producing

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
\iterate ->\dimen 0=3pt 
                        \global \dimen 0=4pt \iftrue \relax \expandafter \it...
l.11 \repeat

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In theory you can change the stack size in `texmf.cnf` but in this cygwin texlive 2019 I can only reduce it from its default 80000 so

```
save_size  = 90000
```

has no effect but

```
save_size  = 1000
```

changes the error to

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=1000].
\iterate ->\dimen 0=3pt 
                        \global \dimen 0=4pt \iftrue \relax \expandafter \it...
l.11 \repeat

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Is this work on Windows? This issue occurs on iPadOS.

Comment: the above file will give the same error on any tex implementation. It uses an arbitrary amount of stack, your document is most likely the same, you need to fix the macros not look at the tex implementation.